# Concatenate an underscore with a string in Postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql, concatenation

I'm trying to build up a string that will look like this in Postgres 9.3.

```
2015_2_23_10
```

It's the current year, month, day, and hour, separated by underscores.

Here's the query that creates the string

```
select 
    cast(extract(year from now()) as text) || '_' ||
    cast(extract(month from now()) as text) || '_' ||
    cast(extract(day from now()) as text) || '_' ||
    cast(extract(hour from now()) as text);
```

However, the underscores get turned into spaces.  I also tried prefacing the underscores with an E, like so `...|| E'_' || ...`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: It works. Probably you are doing it in pgadmin, am I right? In output panel you cannot see underscore. Just try copy and paste it in text editor.

Comment: @user_0 Yup.  I was doing this in pgadmin.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: This can be done much simpler using `to_char(now(), 'yyyy_mm_dd_hh24')`

Comment: Nothing wrong with your sql, see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/baccf/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simple this way instead.

```
select to_char(now(), 'yyyy_MM_DD_hh24');
```

See Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cb05e/3

@courtesy *a_horse_with_no_name*